Flextable does not work anymore in quarto documents - Error: ! package or namespace load failed for 'flextable'
I love flextable and so I use it in a lot of projects.
After setup of a new Laptop where I installed R 4.4.1 and RStudio 2024.04.2 I had to see that

the flextable library (0.9.6) produces an error when it is attached in a quarto document (.qmd) but
there is no problem when it is attached in a RMarkdown document (.Rmd).

The error occurs immediately after klicking the render button of a .qmd file and looks like this:

Quitting from lines 9-13 [setup] (flextable_test.qmd)
Error:
! package or namespace load failed for 'flextable':
.onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'shiny', details:
call: .make_numeric_version(x, strict, .standard_regexps()$valid_numeric_version)
error: invalid non-character version specification 'x' (type: double)
Backtrace:

base::library(flextable)
base::tryCatch(...)
base (local) tryCatchList(expr, classes, parentenv, handlers)
base (local) tryCatchOne(expr, names, parentenv, handlers[[1L]])
value[3L]


To reproduce that error it is only necessary to

create a new quarto document,
include library(flextable),
save the file in a directory 'project/src' and
render it.

To solve that error I tried to deinstall and install flextable again but that did not help.
Can anyone explain to me what that error message means exactly?

Looks similar to this issue, which should be fixed in 0.9.6. I find it curious that the error message mentions shiny. Try installing the development version from GitHub. If the error still occurs, report it to the flextable issue tracker.

Thanks for the quick reply @Roland. 
I just tried  

devtools::install_github("davidgohel/flextable")  

and got this message 
Error in .make_numeric_version(x, strict, .standard_regexps()$valid_numeric_version) :
invalid non-character version specification 'x' (type: double)
Downloading GitHub repo davidgohel/flextable@HEAD 
Anyway also that development version does not help, so I will report that issue as suggested

I don't know what exactly happens here, but after upgrading shiny to 1.9.1 the problem seems to be solved.
Now I do not receive an error message. :-)
